# problems setting up postgis and importing data

Tags: postgis-2.0, mac

Using Postgres 9.2.3.1 on a new Mac.  I installed Postgres from the dmg file that I downloaded from the Postgres site.  I then installed PostGIS using stackbuilder. This all worked flawlessly so far as I can tell.

I have tweaked the pg_hba.conf file to trust connections from local and localhost and created a database "db".  Then I tried::

```
Mac-mini:pg postgres$ bin/createlang plpgsql db
createlang: language "plpgsql" is already installed in database "db"
```

so it would appear that postgres knows all about postgis.

When I tried:

```
Mac-mini:pg postgres$ bin/shp2pgsql -c ~rful011/tmp/weed_boundaries weed_plot_boundaries | psql db
Shapefile type: Arc
Postgis type: MULTILINESTRING[2]
SET
SET
BEGIN
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "weed_plot_boundaries_gid_seq" for serial column "weed_plot_boundaries.gid"
CREATE TABLE
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "weed_plot_boundaries_pkey" for table "weed_plot_boundaries"
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','weed_plot_boundaries','geom','0...
               ^
```

I must have missed something but what?

Thanks, Russell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating plpgsql is usually not enough. You also have to create all spatial functions. In Ubuntu, this is how it's done:

```
createdb postgis_template
createlang plpgsql postgis_template
psql -d postgis_template -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql
psql -d postgis_template -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

Comment: ran those commands modulo path names to pg install dir. but still get the same error. I then listed the databases I found I had them duplicated.  Not enough space left to post \l output :(

Comment: oops hit return again.  \l showed 
    postgis_template
     postgres
     template0
     template1
     template_postgis

so I think I already had those created.

Comment: Well, the database "db" you're trying to load into is not PostGIS enabled. Create a test database using postgis_template and try to load into that.

Comment: Ah!  I get it.  postgis_template is just a database name not something magical -- All the docs I have seen use that name so I thought is was part of the incantation.

That is what I had failed to understand.  Replaced "db" with "postgis_template" and it works.

As always, thanks for your help!